# How to Deploy a jRuby App?

Tags: ruby, deployment, rubygems, jruby

Just wondering if anyone has any experience on how to "deploy" a JRuby application to another server?

That is I am developing a jRuby Application on Windows, and I want to eventually deploy it to a host of Linux/Unix Servers. So specifically -

- How easy is it too deploy or just a nightmare?
- Would I have to recompile all the "gems" (dependencies) or try figure out a way to bundle them as a deploy package? Or would I have to configure jRuby individually per server as I did on my Dev Machine (Windows Box)

PS. The App is made up of Client/Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [trinidad](https://github.com/trinidad/trinidad) or [warbler](https://github.com/jruby/warbler); it wraps up most of these issues.

Comment: Thanks Dave, have you done an implementation yourself perhaps? Looking for some experience and insight into the matter.

Comment: @DaneBalia What kind of "experience and insight"? We deploy through Webistrano and had no issues. Not sure what you mean by "recompiling all the gems".